# validate the number of inputs in c

Tags: c

I'm writing a code which needs to accept command line input. input validation is part of the marking criteria so I'm writing a piece of code to check that exactly one number is entered so I can put it in the main code later (adding an else case for invalid input to bug the user)

```
#include<stdio.h> 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    double a;

    a = 75;


    if(argc == 2);
    {
        sscanf(argv[1], "%lf", &a);
        printf("%lf \n", a);
    }

    printf("%d% \n", argc);

    return(0); 
}
```

the program prints a when at least one argument is on the command line but it prints a segmentation fault when no argument is entered and still scans when more than one are.

help?

Comment: I think it's the condition that's broken but I can't see how ><

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(argc == 2);
```

is equivalent to

```
if(argc == 2)
    ;
```

You need to remove the `;` to have the block after this be executed conditionally

```
if(argc == 2)
//           ^ no trailing ; now
{
    sscanf(argv[1], "%lf", &a); // now only executed if argc == 2
```